# Vector proportional to column of cofactors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix over real numbers with rank $n-1$, and let $v$ be a vector such that $Av=0$. Let $p_{i}$ be the cofactor at position $(i,1)$. Suppose that $p_i> 0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Is it true that $p$ and $v$ must be parallel vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for any $1 \le i \le n$ that 
$$ 0 = \delta_{j1} \det A = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i a_{i,j} = -\sum_{i=1}^n a_{j,i}p_i $$
That is $Ap = 0$, where $p = (p_1, \ldots, p_n)^t$. As $A$ has rank $n-1$, we have $\dim\ker A = 1$, and as $p$ and $v$ are both elements of the kernel, we must have $p = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in F$, where $F$ denotes the base field.